# Neural network illustrations

Tags: graphics, output-formatting, neural-networks

*(Since this post was met with a certain reluctance to be given answers, [a version of it](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1360660) is also posted in [Community](http://community.wolfram.com/).)*

Please share neural networks diagrams you have made in Mathematica / WL. Here is an example:

```
ClearAll[a];
ns = {3, 4, 6, 4, 1};
nodes = MapIndexed[Function[{n, i}, Prepend[#, i[[1]]] & /@ Array[a, {n}]], ns];
edges = Map[Outer[Rule, #[[1]], #[[2]]] &, Partition[nodes, 2, 1]];
colors = Map[# -> ColorData[11, "ColorList"][[#[[1]]]] &, Flatten[nodes]];
Graph[Flatten[edges], VertexSize -> 0.3, VertexStyle -> colors]
```

[image]

But, [here are some more examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=neural+network&source=lnms&tbm=isch&).

### Update

Addressing the concerns in the comments...

The question is intentionally given with a short explanation and a link to examples. I wanted to gather some pictures of neural networks made with Mathematica for a few presentations about deep learning. (Like this [Mathematica-vs-R over deep learning presentation](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaVsR/tree/master/Projects/DeepLearningExamples).) I was somewhat surprised that such images were not easy to find.

What I am interested in are images like these:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Share examples" is not a question.  why don't you simply replace the node numbers in your own code?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork " 'Share examples' is not a question. why don't you simply replace the node numbers in your own code?" -- Please take a look at [Vitaliy Kaurov's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175710/34008). Its submission addresses the first part of your comment; its content the second part.

Comment: To the "close" voters: **1.** How come if this question is "too broad" there are two specific answers already? **2.** If this question is "primarily opinion based", how come we recognize an image of a neural network when we see it? Did you look at the images in [the provided link](https://www.google.com/search?q=neural+network&source=lnms&tbm=isch&)?

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but this question is FAR too broad.  What if an artist "asked":  "please make a drawing"?  Your question gives us no hint at WHY you want "examples."  Is it to highlight links?  To enable massively large networks to be easily understood?  Is it to show the nonlinearities in each node?  Is it to show the weight **values**?  A question should be able to be *accepted* but with your vague and broad "question," no matter what "answer" you "accept," there will be an infinity of other "answers," many even "better."  This is no way to ask a question.  (Now I'm voting to close.)

Comment: I do not want to continue arguing with David G. Stork but his previous comment is too prominently "featured" in this question and I find it *only* mostly right. **1.** "[...] this question is FAR too broad[...]" -- It is not that broad; images of neural networks are easily recognized (and apparently some people can relatively easily do them.) I did not want to influence the answers with more specific question formulations. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) **2.** "A question should be able to be accepted[...]" -- This is a good rule for most of the questions posted and to be posted at MSE. There are notable exceptions, like [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice), and I can come up easily with at least 5 more. **3.** "This is no way to ask a question." -- Apparently it is. **4.** "(Now I'm voting to close.)" -- I appreciate being upfront, but I am not sure the close-voting was done with having in mind what is best for MSE's users.

Comment: asks:  "To the "close" voters: 1. How come if this question is "too broad" there are two specific answers already?"  Simple.  Just ask the broadest possible question you can imagine, e.g., "What might be a good book to read?" and you can get a specific answer ("Bad Blood").  The fact that you get a specific answer implies nothing whatsoever as to whether the question was "too broad."  Examples:  1) What's a good restaurant in China?  2) How would you improve Renaissance art?  3) How can you draw a world map differently?  (Like the OP) "I am interested are images like these?" Why?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Your last comment is just an expansion of a previous argument you did. (To which I gave a response.) Do you have anything new to add? Also, why do you continue posting here? Do you still hope that this question is going be closed or neglected because of your comments or votes?

Comment: Closed.  Your response or "answers" consist of unsupported assertions, such as "Apparently it is" (because you did it and so you think it must be right).  I've rebutted all such non-answer "answers" with actual reasons and examples.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork **1.** "I've rebutted all such non-answer "answers" with actual reasons and examples." -- No, you have not rebuffed anything. Even if we ignore my arguments in the comments above, the existence of the answers posted below is a very good contra-argument to your objections. **2.** "Closed" -- You still want this question closed!? Do you think that closing this question would make MSE more useful? Do you think that removing this question and its answers would make MSE more useful?

Comment: "the existence of the answers... is a very good contra-argument to your objections." No... as my vague "book" questions with specific answers demonstrates.  And yes:  I think that closing this would make MSE more useful and focus attention on *specific* Qs.  By the way, I wrote one of the world's leading textbooks on neural networks (nearing 100k sales, 4 languages, used in every leading university, ...) and wrestled how to best present networks, including deep ones.  I confronted SPECIFIC, detailed problems in doing so... and never asked "please draw me one" as it wouldn't help.  Over/out.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork **1.** "And yes: I think that closing this would make MSE more useful and focus attention on specific Qs." -- It seems that a fair amount of people disagree with you. **2.** "I wrote one of the world's leading textbooks on neural networks (nearing 100k sales, 4 languages[...]" -- Great! So, because of your Neural Networks expertise this question got a disproportionate amount of your attention.

Answer (score 23):

Below is given a function definition that can be used to make a neural network plot with formulae and activation functions graphics. The code/plot can be garnished some more, but at this point I find it good enough...

```
Clear[FormulaNeuralNetworkGraph]
FormulaNeuralNetworkGraph[layerCounts : {_Integer, _Integer, _Integer}] :=      
  Block[{gr1, gr2, gr3, gr4, gr, bc},
   gr1 = IndexGraph[CompleteGraph[Take[layerCounts, 2]]];
   gr2 = Graph[Map[(layerCounts[[1]] + #) \[UndirectedEdge] (layerCounts[[1]] + layerCounts[[2]] + #) &, Range[layerCounts[[2]]]]];
   gr3 = IndexGraph[CompleteGraph[Take[layerCounts, -2]], layerCounts[[1]] + layerCounts[[2]] + 1];
   bc = layerCounts[[1]] + 2*layerCounts[[2]];
   gr4 = Graph[Map[(bc + #) \[UndirectedEdge] (bc + layerCounts[[3]] + #) &, Range[layerCounts[[3]]]], VertexLabels -> "Name"];
   gr = GraphUnion[gr1, gr2, gr3, gr4];
   Graph[gr, 
    GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", 
      "VertexPartition" -> {layerCounts[[1]], layerCounts[[2]], 
        layerCounts[[2]], layerCounts[[3]], layerCounts[[3]]}}]
   ];

Clear[FormulaNeuralNetworkGraphPlot]
Options[FormulaNeuralNetworkGraphPlot] = Options[Graphics];

FormulaNeuralNetworkGraphPlot[layerCounts : {_Integer, _Integer, _Integer}, func1_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=      
  FormulaNeuralNetworkGraphPlot[layerCounts, func1, # &, opts];

FormulaNeuralNetworkGraphPlot[
   layerCounts : {_Integer, _Integer, _Integer}, func1_, func2_, 
   opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=      
  Block[{plOpts, grFunc1, grFunc2, gr, vNames, vCoords, vNameToCoordsRules, edgeLines},
   plOpts = {PlotTheme -> "Default", Axes -> True, Ticks -> False, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> False, ImageSize -> Small};
   grFunc1 = Plot[func1[x], {x, -2, 2}, Evaluate[plOpts]];
   grFunc2 = Plot[func2[x], {x, -2, 2}, Evaluate[plOpts]];
  
   gr = FormulaNeuralNetworkGraph[layerCounts];
   vNames = VertexList[gr];
   vCoords = VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions[gr, VertexCoordinates];
   vNameToCoordsRules = Thread[vNames -> vCoords]; 
   edgeLines = Arrow@ReplaceAll[List @@@ EdgeList[gr], vNameToCoordsRules]; 

   Graphics[{
     Arrowheads[0.02], GrayLevel[0.2], edgeLines,

     EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Gray], 
     Map[Disk[#, 0.04] &, vCoords[[1 ;; -layerCounts[[-1]] - 1]]],

     Black,
     Map[{EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[White], Disk[#, 0.14], 
        Text[Style["\[Sum]", 16, Bold], #]} &,
      Join[
       vCoords[[layerCounts[[1]] + 1 ;; layerCounts[[1]] + layerCounts[[2]]]],
       vCoords[[-2 layerCounts[[-1]] ;; -layerCounts[[-1]] - 1]]
       ]],

     Map[{EdgeForm[None], FaceForm[White], 
        Rectangle[# - {0.2, 0.15}, # + {0.2, 0.15}], 
        Inset[grFunc1, #1, Center, 0.4]} &, 
      vCoords[[ Total[layerCounts[[1 ;; 2]]] + 1 ;; Total[layerCounts[[1 ;; 2]]] + layerCounts[[2]]] ]],

     Map[{EdgeForm[None], FaceForm[White], 
        Rectangle[# - {0.2, 0.15}, # + {0.2, 0.15}], 
        Inset[grFunc2, #1, Center, 0.4]} &, 
      MapThread[Mean@*List, {vCoords[[-2 layerCounts[[-1]] ;; -layerCounts[[-1]] - 1]], vCoords[[-layerCounts[[-1]] ;; -1]]}]]}, 
    opts]
   ];
```

Note that the function `FormulaNeuralNetworkGraphPlot` takes the options of `Graphics`.

```
 FormulaNeuralNetworkGraphPlot[{5, 9, 6}, Tanh, #^3 &,  ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

(I tried to reuse as much as I can the code from [the answer of Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175774/34008). I had to move to using `Graphics` because I had hard time insetting the activation functions plots using the multi-partite graph options.)

Comment: Very cool! like the graph in text book

Comment: @partida Thanks, good to hear!

Answer (score 21):

The key is `GraphLayout -> "MultipartiteEmbedding"`.

```
layerCounts = {5, 3, 3, 8, 2};

graph = GraphUnion @@ MapThread[
    IndexGraph,
    {CompleteGraph /@ Partition[layerCounts, 2, 1], 
     FoldList[Plus, 0, layerCounts[[;; -3]]]}
    ];

vstyle = Catenate[
  Thread /@ Thread[
    TakeList[VertexList[graph], layerCounts] -> ColorData[97] /@ Range@Length[layerCounts]
    ]
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
graph = Graph[
  graph,
  GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> layerCounts},
  GraphStyle -> "BasicBlack",
  VertexSize -> 0.5,
  VertexStyle -> vstyle
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This won't work for only two layers because `GraphUnion` is being unreasonable when given a single argument. You can complain to WRI support about that, or implement a workaround.

Comment: Brilliant. "You can complain to WRI support about that, or implement a workaround." I might do both! By the way, at [EWTC-2018](https://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference-eu/2018/) last week, during the "Quiz the Experts: Q&A", somebody did ask about graph functionalities development and support with more-or-less similar concerns as those you voiced in Community.

Answer (score 17):

[image]

A bit different function that always places vertices symmetrically:

```
LayersGraph[layers_]:=
Module[{
    uni=Table[Unique[],#]&/@layers,
    coor=Flatten[Table[{k,#}&/@(Range[#]-Mean[Range[#]]&/@layers)[[k]],{k,Length[layers]}],1]},
Graph[
    Flatten[uni],
    Flatten[Outer[Rule,#1,#2]&@@@Partition[uni,2,1]],
VertexCoordinates->coor,
EdgeShapeFunction->"Line",VertexSize->.3]
]
```

Usage that gives the image above:

```
LayersGraph[{2, 2, 3, 7, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1}]
```

A bit different version would go like:

```
LayersGraph[layers_]:=
Module[{
    vert=TakeList[Range[Total[layers]],layers],
    coor=Flatten[Table[{k,#}&/@(Range[#]-Mean[Range[#]]&/@layers)[[k]],{k,Length[layers]}],1]},
Graph[
    Flatten[vert],
    Flatten[Outer[Rule,#1,#2]&@@@Partition[vert,2,1]],
VertexCoordinates->coor,
EdgeShapeFunction->"Line",GraphStyle->"SmallNetwork"]
]

LayersGraph[{2, 2, 3, 7, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: The `LayersGraph` function you provided is great! Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Using `CompleteGraph` with a list of layer sizes as input and deleting edges that connect non-consecutive layers:

```
ClearAll[layeredNW]
layeredNW[layers : {__}, opts : OptionsPattern[Graph]] := Module[{cg = 
    CompleteGraph[layers, DirectedEdges -> True]}, 
  SetProperty[EdgeDelete[cg, DirectedEdge[a_, b_] /; 
     (Subtract @@ (PropertyValue[{cg, #} , VertexCoordinates][[1]] & /@ {b, a}) > 1)], 
   {PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", VertexSize -> .5, VertexStyle -> White, 
    EdgeStyle -> Black, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[cg], opts}]]
```

Example:

```
layers = {2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1};
colors = Flatten[MapThread[ConstantArray,
      {ColorData[63, "ColorList"][[;; Length@layers]], layers}]];

layeredNW[layers, VertexStyle -> {i_ :> colors[[i]]}, ImageSize -> Large, VertexSize -> .3]
```

[image]

### Stress-test

```
layers = {2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1}*5;
colors = Flatten[
   MapThread[
    ConstantArray, {ColorData[63, "ColorList"][[;; Length@layers]], 
     layers}]];

layeredNW[layers, VertexStyle -> {i_ :> colors[[i]]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, VertexSize -> .7, ImageSize -> 1600]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer! Please consider coming up with other stress-tests than the one I posted. I tried with three-four times larger number of nodes than the image I posted. I think your and Szabolcs approaches handle larger specs of neural networks nodes better than the other posts.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that the code is clean, but once I had to make a graph that has a fixed size in all layers (except those with one node). I put it as is just for diversity reasons, may be it will inspire somebody.

```
nList = {2, 7, 9, 1}; (* nodes by layers *)
```

Main functions:

```
nEmbed[nList_List] := Module[{list, nRagged, ragged},
   nRagged[list_List] := 
    Internal`PartitionRagged[Range[Total@list], list];
   ragged = nRagged[nList];
   
   (* returns flatten join of all 'matrixes of connections' between \
layers *)
   
   Flatten@(Outer[Rule, Sequence @@ #] & /@ 
      Table[ragged[[i]], {i, Partition[Range[Length@nList], 2, 1]}])
   ];


nCoord [nList_List] := 
  Module[{list, nRagged, ragged, coordy, coordx, k = 3}, 
   nRagged[list_List] := 
    Internal`PartitionRagged[Range[Total@list], list];
   ragged = nRagged[nList];
   
   (* coordy reflects vertical layout, 
   coordx uses the same function but can be corrected with k *)
   
   coordy[rag_List /; Length[rag] == 1] := {5.};
   coordy[rag_List /; Length[rag] > 1] := 
    Table[i N[10./(Length[rag] - 1), 2], {i, 0, Length[rag] - 1}];
   coordx = coordy;
   
   (* coordx applies to the layers (and so nodes), 
   but coordy applies to nodes in respective layers *)
   
   Thread[Range[Total@nList] -> 
     Flatten[(Thread /@ Thread[{k (coordx @ #), coordy /@ #}] &) @ 
       ragged, 1]]
   ];
```

Usage:

```
Graph[nEmbed[#], VertexCoordinates -> nCoord[#], 
   VertexLabels -> "Name",
   VertexSize -> 0.3,
   EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line",
   ImageSize -> Large] &@ nList
```

[image]

For some sort of stress-test with `nList = {8, 17, 19, 6, 4, 3};`.

[image]