# Built-in way to draw LinearLayer graph

Tags: neural-networks

Newer versions of Mathematica come with built-in tooling for training and simulating neural networks.

For a simple `LinearLayer`, e.g. `LinearLayer[2, "Weights" -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, "Biases" -> {0, 0}]` I want to produce a graph showing:

- The input and output nodes in the network
- The biases
- The connections, and respective weights

For example, something like the diagram below (though obviously without the hidden layer for a simple LinearLayer)

[image]
<sub>(source: [lol768.com](https://lol768.com/i/FenAccreditedLaudCompensatory))</sub>

Is this possible?

MATLAB has the [view function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/view.html), but it's fairly limited too.

Comment: Where the weights and biases are represented in the showed diagram?

Comment: Related discussion: ["Neural network illustrations"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175686/34008).

Comment: "Where the weights and biases are represented in the showed diagram?" - they're not, but I normally draw the weights as edge labels, and the biases/thresholds inside the nodes.

Answer (score 12):

Using `CompleteGraph` with a list of layer sizes as the first argument and deleting undesired edges:

```
ClearAll[nwG]
nwG[layers : {__}, opts : OptionsPattern[Graph]] :=  Module[{nf = First@layers, 
    nl = Last@layers, cg = CompleteGraph[Flatten[{First@layers, layers, Last@layers}], 
     DirectedEdges -> True]}, 
  cg = EdgeDelete[cg, {DirectedEdge[a_, b_] /; 
      (Subtract @@ (PropertyValue[{cg, #}, VertexCoordinates][[1]] & /@ {b, a}) > 1), 
     DirectedEdge[v1_, v2_] /; Or[And[v1 <= nf, v2 != nf + v1], 
       And[v2 >= 1 + VertexCount[cg] - nl, v1 != v2 - nl]]}];
  SetProperty[cg, {PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
    VertexShapeFunction ->
      {Alternatives @@ Join[Take[VertexList[cg], nf], Take[VertexList[cg], -nl]] :> None},
    VertexSize -> .5, VertexStyle -> White, 
    EdgeStyle -> Black, EdgeLabelStyle -> 16, 
    VertexCoordinates -> (ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}]@ GraphEmbedding[cg]), 
    EdgeLabels -> {DirectedEdge[v : Alternatives @@ Range[nf], _] :> 
         Placed[Subscript["I", v], 1/2],
      ## & @@ MapIndexed[DirectedEdge[_, #] -> Placed[Subscript["O", #2[[1]]], 1/2] &, 
        Take[VertexList[cg], -nl]]}, opts}]]
```

**Examples:**

```
g0 = nwG[{5, 3, 1}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
SetProperty[g0, {VertexSize -> .9, VertexStyle -> {11 -> Yellow}, 
  VertexCoordinates -> (ScalingTransform[{2, 1}]@GraphEmbedding[g0])}]
```

[image]

```
layers = {5, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4};
nwG[layers, VertexStyle -> {23 -> Red}, ImageSize -> Large, ImagePadding -> Scaled[.03],
 Epilog -> {Text["First\nLayer", {1, 4}], Text["Third\nLayer", {3, 4}], 
    Text["Seventh\nLayer", {7, 4}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Please add this answer to the related discussion: ["Neural network illustrations"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175686/34008).

Comment: @AntonAntonov, posted a modified version of `nwG` in the linked q/a.

Comment: So I'm guessing in terms of a "built-in", there isn't anything available?

What would it take to get the connection weights added as edge labels, and the biases in the nodes with your solution? Could it take a LinearLayer/NetChain as an argument?

Comment: @Adam, afaik there is no built-in function.  You can add edge/vertex labels using `EdgeLabels`/`VertexLabels`. I don't know  about the structure of  `LinearLayer/NetChain` objects to extract the needed components as inputs to `Graph`.

Comment: @AdamWilliams I am working on a repository function for all of this for my current research (will present at WTC, if interested) it is a combination of weight/bias visualizations ala a custom style (I will add options for these labels it seems), a layer/connection organizer for adjacency graphs (the input to the research-based function), and some automated network constructions. The neuron behavior is outside of the normal neural networks functionality (time-based behavior of activations aka spiking networks) so everything is being custom made from the ground up. I’ll be sure to tag you!

Comment: This sounds awesome @CATrevillian - keep me updated for sure :)