# Is is possible to plot a multilayer network?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks

I would like to generate and plot a network of networks, otherwise known as a multilayer network. That is, I have one network of type A nodes with type a links. I have another network of type B nodes with type b links. Some type A nodes are also linked to type B nodes with type c links. Is there a way to graphically represent this using the standard network tools in Mathematica?

Ultimately, I would also like to do community detection on this multilayer network. First, I would like to detect communities within each network (A and B types) separately. Then I would like to detect communities in the overall network of networks, which contains both node types and three link types. I'm aware of algorithms for doing this but don't know whether they've been implemented in Mathematica previously. Any advice would be hugely appreciated.

The purpose of all this is to illustrate broad concepts so the details of the networks don't matter so much, as long as they look nice in the plot.

Many thanks!

Comment: This - https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175686/neural-network-illustrations/175900 - may give you some hints.