# How to create a representation of a multilayered neural network from scratch using Graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

One valid way is given at the end.

I thought `CompleteGraph[{2, 3, 3, 1}]` would create the representation that I wanted but it creates too many edges (from the first layer to the third layer, etc). Instead of that, this works:

```
q = {2, 3, 3, 1};
qf = MapThread[
   Range[#1, #2] &, {Prepend[Most[Accumulate[q]], 0] + 1, 
    Accumulate[q]}];
qp = Flatten@
   Map[UndirectedEdge @@@ # &][Tuples /@ Partition[qf, 2, 1]];
Graph[qp]
```

But it only works for very simple layers. For example,

```
q = {2, 3, 5, 8, 1};
...
```

creates a graph that is clustered rather than layered. One could give options to Graph, such as

```
Graph[qp, 
 GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left}]
```

but for some reason, one of the nodes from the two of the first layer is arranged so as to be not in the first layer. So I don't know how to specify the method for specific GraphLayouts.

I could also not guide "MultipartiteEmbedding" into the correct behavior

```
Graph[qp, 
 GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> q}
```

because the layout confuses the layers due to the given ordering of qp (places a node from the first layer on the second, and a node from the second on the first).

This works:

```
q = {2, 3, 5, 8, 1};
qf = MapThread[
   Range[#1 + 1, #2] &, {Prepend[Most[Accumulate[q]], 0], 
    Accumulate[q]}];
qp = Flatten@
   Map[UndirectedEdge @@@ # &][Tuples /@ Partition[qf, 2, 1]];
qc = GraphEmbedding[CompleteGraph[q]];
Graph[qp, VertexCoordinates -> Map[# -> qc[[#]] &, Range[Total[q]]]]
```

I started playing around with neural nets so I wanted a clean representation of one to have as a map on the side.

Is there a function or option specifically for this? Are there other ways of doing this? Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Maybe this is useful? https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1360660
Also: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175686/neural-network-illustrations/175774#175774

Comment: Definitely! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the option `GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> q}` and use the first argument of `Graph` to provide the list of vertices

```
Graph[Range[Total@q], qp, 
 GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> q}]
```

[image]

You can also delete unwanted edges from `CompleteGraph[q]`:

```
EdgeDelete[#,  a_ <-> b_ /; Abs[Subtract @@ GraphEmbedding[#][[{a, b}, 1]]] > 1] & @
 CompleteGraph[q]
```

[image]